# Check if a string doesn't contain any substring from list of substrings in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to do the following logic:

```
bitmap_id = 'HelloWorld'
if 'SLIDE' not in bitmap_id and 'ICON' not in bitmap_id  and 'BOT' not in bitmap_id:
    print bitmap_id
```

So if bitmap_id is 'ICON_helloworld', then nothing should be printed.

I'm pretty sure you all agree that it's too long and looks ugly, so I tried to do it as shown below, but it's not working.

```
if any(s not in bitmap_id for s in ['SLIDE', 'ICON', 'BOT']):
    print bitmap_id
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried declaring the table out of the command line, and just make a `for` loop for each string in the table ?

Comment: It looks to me like in your first statement you are using 'and' but in your second statement you have an implicit 'or'.

Comment: @ypnos thanks heaps for hint, I'm new to Python and didn't know of the all function :) your comment was sufficient for me to find the answer quickly

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use either

```
if all(s not in bitmap_id for s in ['SLIDE', 'ICON', 'BOT']):
     print bitmap_id
```

or

```
if not any(s in bitmap_id for s in ['SLIDE', 'ICON', 'BOT']):
    print bitmap_id
```

Answer (score 3):

You need actually:

```
if all(s not in bitmap_id for s in ['SLIDE', 'ICON', 'BOT']):
    print bitmap_id
```

`if any` will be false only if all of the of the strings are in `bitmap_id`, for example `'bitmap_id = 'ICON_SLIDE_BOT'`. You want opposite, that none of the strings are there or all strings are not there.

Comment: you got the answer over DeepSpace by one minute! Sorry for the late acceptance! actually forgot bout this question as you guys answered it so fast I had to wait to accept! cheers,

Comment: @sayo9394 I actually like his answer more, he has 2 options.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
bitmap_id = 'HelloWorld'
blacklist = ['SLIDE', 'ICON', 'BOT']
if not filter(lambda x: x in bitmap_id, blacklist):
    print bitmap_id
```